# Errors at catkin_make for laser_scan_matcher

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to work with Polar Scan Matcher and Canonical Scan Matcher (laser_scan_matcher) from Scan_tools. So far, I've been able to run the demo.launch for PSM, but not (yet) to use my own LRF. Nevertheless, when trying to use the CSM demo, I receive an error as follows:

**ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_scan_matcher/laser_scan_matcher_node]: can't locate node [laser_scan_matcher_node] in package [laser_scan_matcher]**

Reading, I found out that the problem is because there is no executable ready. I tried once more to do catkin_make (I did it once when installing scan_tools), and pay attention to the output. I found this:

> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/home/antonio/PSM/build/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/csm/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> make[2]: *** [scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/csm/stamp/csm_src-configure] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/CMakeFiles/csm_src.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> Invoking "make" failed

I've also tried **rosrun laser_scan_matcher** and tried to see the options with *tab* but none appears.

My settings are ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04.

This is what I've got so far with my little knowledge. I hope someone can help me fix this.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197658/errors-at-catkin_make-for-laser_scan_matcher/) by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-18**:
Is there a package.xml or a manifest.xml in the package?

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2014-11-18**:
I just got the demo working on my machine with:

- $ cd [indigo catkin workspace directory]
   - $ git clone  https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git
- $ sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
   - $  catkin_make
- $ roslaunch laser_scan_matcher demo.launch

Is this what you did?

**Comment by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) on 2014-11-19**:
@dornhege Yes, the package has its proper xml files thank you!

@Angus Thank you so much, you should have written your post as answer! I missed to install the compiling library. I didn't know about it though. Now it's running and time for some tests using the real thing. Thank you!

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2014-11-19**:
Awesome! I'll just reply with an answer so we can mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per the comments, the demo seems to work on Inidigo with these commands:

```
$ cd [indigo catkin workspace directory]
$ git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools
$ sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
$ catkin_make
$ roslaunch laser_scan_matcher demo.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) on 2014-11-20**:
The **libgs10-dev** is the library to compile correctly the package with catkin_make. That was the main problem.

Thank you Angus!

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2014-12-04**:
Indeed! Installing the libgsl0-dev solved it for me too using the Hydro branch. Thank you =).

**Comment by [rosRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23646/rosrabbit/) on 2015-08-26**:
It works for me. Thanks for sharing! :)

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-08-13**:
Works for Kinetic as well

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Slight modification to @Angus' answer as a more systematic, flexible approach:

```
- $ sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
+ $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro %YOUR_ROS_DISTRO% -r
```

This `rosdep` command installs all the missing system dependency (must be described in `package.xml`) in all the packages in your src directory.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2